# data-sort on click not working to find table

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to get a notification when a table is clicked, more specifically the headers. But for some reason the following code is resulting in no action happening.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('[data-sort="true"]').on('click', function(){
        console.log('click!');
    });
});
```

My Table looks something like this:

```
<table id="tldPricingTable" data-sort="true">
   <thead>
     <tr>
       ....
     </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      ....
   </tbody>
</table>
```

What am I missing?

Comment: because there isnt any `td` or `th` in your table add them and the code will work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your code works ok (see https://jsfiddle.net/m8hd1au6/6/)

```
<table id="tldPricingTable" data-sort="true">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Hello</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <td>Hello</td>
  </tbody>
</table>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('[data-sort="true"]').on('click', function(){
        console.log('click!');
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: So it's the router I'm using causing problems again. Got it. Thank you. Sorry for wasting time!!!!

Comment: It is ok, No Problem :-)